Page Freezing When Storing Data from EventSource in Redux
In my React project, I'm using EventSource to receive 10 objects per second from the server, and I'm storing these objects in the Redux store. When the data size reaches 8000 objects, the page freezes. However, when I fetch the same data using an HTTP GET request, I can handle up to 50000 objects without any issues, and the page doesn't freeze.
What could be causing the page to freeze when using EventSource? How can I resolve this?
When I use an HTTP GET request, I can store up to 50,000 data points in Redux without the page freezing, but when I use EventSource, the page crashes with just 8,000 data points.

The code I use EventSource is as below, in this section, 10 objects come in seconds and I dispatch to redux as in the following code
useEffect(() => {
        const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/events');

        eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
            const newMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
            dispatch(
                addMapData({
                    DefectX: newMessage.DefectPosX,
                    DefectY: newMessage.DefectPosY,
                    DefectArea: newMessage.DefectArea,
                }),
            );
            dispatch(changeDefectList(newMessage));
        };

        eventSource.onerror = (err) => {
            console.error('EventSource failed:', err);
            eventSource.close();
        };

        return () => {
            eventSource.close();
        };
    }, []);

my test with http get request
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(async () => {
            const res: any = await fetch("http://localhost:3000");
            const resData = await res.json();
            dispatch(
                addMapData({
                    DefectX: resData.DefectPosX,
                    DefectY: resData.DefectPosY,
                    DefectArea: resData.DefectArea,
                }),
            );
            dispatch(changeDefectList(resData));
        }, 100);
    }, []);

